# How to debug the problem not able to translate OID with a new MIB file for UPS-MIB?

Tags: centos, net-snmp, mib

On Centos, I ran into the following error:

```
sudo snmptrap -v 2c -c read localhost '' UPS-MIB::upsTraps
MIB search path: /root/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs
Cannot find module (UPS-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
UPS-MIB::upsTraps: Unknown Object Identifier
```

The above error happened after

1. Copied UPS-MIB.txt to /usr/share/snmp/mibs
2. I started snmptrapd:

   snmptrapd -f -Lo -Dread-config -m ALL

The version of the Net-SNMP is 5.2.x.

The same procedures work fine with Ubuntu 18.04/Net-SNMP 5.3.7.
I wonder how to debug and fix the problem?

Besides the Net-SNMP version difference, on Ubuntu, I found an instruction to install mib-download-tool, and execute it after the installation of Net-SNMP, and comment out the lines beginning with min: in snmp.conf in order to fix the error of missing MIB's.

However, for the Centos, I had no need and found no such instruction, thus I have not done it yet, as there is no error message of missing MIB's.

The MIB file is downloaded from https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1628.txt
renamed to UPS-MIB.txt (It seems to me that the name of the MIB file does not matter, as long as it's unique? I tried to use a different names, upsMIB.txt, rfc1628.txt, but it does not help to improve.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows:
manually copied /usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf/UPS-MIB on an Ubuntu with Net-SNMP 5.7.3 installed to the Centos /usr/share/snmp/mibs/UPS-MIB

then restart the snmpd
by the command:

```
service snmpd restart
```

then the OID of UPS-MIB becomes visible and accessible.

Maybe, the version that I downloaded from https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1628.txt is not suitable??

Comment: The original RFC1628 version had 3 errors that you can find at https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=1628&rec_status=0. Plus, it had some problems with mib-2 that I'm still trying to solve...